# How to pass a block of type dispatch_block_t to a method

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks, dispatch-queue

In the below code, I am trying to pass a block of type `dispatch_block_t` to `dispatch_async` as shown below.
I have tried the following:

```
dispatch_async(defaultPriority, block1(2, 3000));
dispatch_async(defaultPriority, (^block1)(2, 3000));
dispatch_async(defaultPriority, ^(block1)(2, 3000));
```

However the code is not compilable due to a generated error due to how the block is passed to `dispatch_async` method.
Please let me know how to fix it. It would be great if you can provide different ways of passing it if applicable.

```
dispatch_block_t ^block1(int, int) = ^(int x1, int delay) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: delay];
};
dispatch_queue_t defaultPriority = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_queue_t backgroundPriority = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

dispatch_async(defaultPriority, block1(2, 3000));

synchName andId: (NSString *) synchId;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dispatch_block_t` is defined as a block that takes no parameters:

```
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);
```

So, it doesn’t make sense to say “I want to define a block with two parameters as a `dispatch_block_t`” because `dispatch_block_t` takes no parameters.

So, instead, let’s say you want to define a method that takes a block with two parameters. You’d do that like so:

```
- (void)foo:(void (^)(int, int))block {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        block(42, 3);
    });
}
```

Note, I’m not just passing my `block` as the second parameter to `dispatch_async` directly, because `dispatch_block_t` takes no parameters, whereas my block takes two parameters. So, I use the `^{...}` syntax for the second parameter to `dispatch_async`, and inside that block, I call my `block` with the two parameters supplied.

Anyway, you’d call it like so:

```
void (^block1)(int, int) = ^(int value, int delay) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)delay];
    NSLog(@"value = %d", value);
};
[self foo:block1];
```

Or

```
[self foo:^(int value, int delay) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)delay];
    NSLog(@"value = %d", value);
}];
```

If you also wanted to pass the two parameters for the block to `foo`, as well, then add those two parameters:

```
- (void)fooWithValue:(int)value delay:(int)delay block:(void (^)(int, int))block {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        block(value, delay);
    });
}
```

And you’d call it like so:

```
void (^block1)(int, int) = ^(int value, int delay) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)delay];
    NSLog(@"value = %d", value);
};

[self fooWithValue:2 delay:3 block:block1];
```

---

The virtue of the `dispatch_block_t` type is that it gets us out of the above, arcane block syntax. But we can define custom types for whatever combination of parameters we might need:

```
typedef void (^CustomBlock)(int, int);
```

This is just like `dispatch_block_t`, except this one takes two integer parameters.

Then you can do things like:

```
- (void)fooWithValue:(int)value delay:(int)delay block:(CustomBlock)block {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        block(value, delay);
    });
}
```

And

```
CustomBlock block1 = ^(int value, int delay) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)delay];
    NSLog(@"value = %d", value);
};

[self fooWithValue:2 delay:3 block:block1];
```

This syntax for blocks is pretty confusing to remember, so http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com is a good cheatsheet if you forget the syntax.

---

By the way, your code references “delay” in conjunction with `sleepForTimeInterval`. You generally don’t want to use `sleepForTimeInterval`. You would generally use `dispatch_after`, e.g. to do something in 3 seconds, you would do:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self doSomething];
});
```